# HTML CSS & JAVASCRIPT Doesn't Work as Coded When Returning to a Page After Pressing the Back Arrow Button on the Browser

Tags: html, css, button, browser, back

The HTML, CSS, and JAVASCRIPT all work as I would like them to. That is until I return to the same page after pressing the back arrow on my browser (I'm currently using Google chrome). For example: when I have the menu bar open on the smartphone browser it stays in one position on the screen as I'd like it to. However, if I return to that page with the menu bar open, the top portion (where the X button is) moves up the screen if I scroll down.

Can you help me fix it so that the code I'm using stays exactly the same even after I go back to the same page after using the back and forward button on my browser?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en; jp;">     
    
<body style="background-color: white; font-family: sans-serif;">
      
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
<title>Koizumi・Home Page</title>
      
<div class="page-wrap">
     
<div class="cp_cont">
<input id="cp_toggle03" type="checkbox"/>
<div class="cp_mobilebar">
<label for="cp_toggle03" class="cp_menuicon">
<span></span>
</label>
</div>
<label id="h-menu_black" class="cp_toggle03" for="cp_menuicon"></label>
<div id="body" class="noscroll"></div>
        
<header class="cp_offcm03">
        
<nav>
<ul style="text-align: center; margin-left: 210px; overflow: hidden;">
            
<li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="Website_Home_Page_English.html">Home</a></li>
<li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="Website_Blog_English.html">Blog</a></li>
<li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="Website_Koizumi_English.html">About Koizumi</a></li>
<li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="Bibliography_English.html">Bibliography</a></li>
    
<div class="searchbar"> 
            
<form id="frmSearch" class="search2" method="get" action="default.html" style=" padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 20px; text-align: right; position: inline;"/>
<input class="search2" id="txtSearch" type="text" name="serach_bar" size="31" maxlength="255" value="" style="center: 396px; top: 185px; width: 180px; height: 26px;"/>
<input class="search1" type="submit" name="submition" value="Search" style=" padding-  
bottom:20px; left: 0px; top: 153px; height: 25px; width: 46px;"/>
<input class="search2" type="hidden" name="sitesearch" value="default.html"/>    
    
</div>
    
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.getElementById('frmSearch').onsubmit = function() {
 window.location = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=site:yoursitename.com ' + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value;
        return false;
    }
    
 document.getElementById('cp_toggle03').onchange = function() {
 if (document.getElementById('cp_toggle03').checked) {
 document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
  } else {
 document.body.style.overflow = "";
  }
}    
    
</script>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    </header>
    </div>
    </div>
        
<br><br><div class="image" style="margin: 10px;">
    
<a href="Website_JapanTravel_English.html"><img src="photos/Home_Page/Travel/Homepage_Travel_English.jpg" alt="Travel" width="85%"></a>
    
<div class=" responsive-image-container"><a href="photos/Blog/Japanese_Culture/Blog/yokai/yokai_English.html"><img src="photos/Home_Page/Yokai/Homepage_yokai_English.jpg" alt="Yokai" width="42.4%"></a> <a href="photos/Links/Kansai/Kansai_html_photos/Kyoto_html_photo/Kyoto/Blog/Kongoji/Kongoji_html_photo/Kongoji_English.html"><img src="photos/Home_Page/Kongoji/Kongoji_homepage_English.jpg" alt="Kongoji" width="42.4%"></a>
</div>
    
<div class=" responsive-image-container"><a href="photos/Links/Kanto/Kanto_html_photos/Saitama_html_photos/Saitama/Blog/Tamagawa_Onsen/Tamagawa_Onsen_html_photo/Tamagawa_Onsen_English.html"><img src="photos/Home_Page/Tamagawa_Onsen/Homepage_Tamagawa_Onsen_English.jpg" alt="Tamagawa_Onsen" width="42.4%"></a> <a href="Website_Koizumi_English.html"><img src="photos/Home_Page/About_Koizumi/Homepage_Koizumi_English.jpg" alt="Koizumi" width="42.4%"></a>
</div>
    
<br><br><footer class="site-footer" style="font-size: 12px;">小泉© | <a href="Website_Home_Page.html">日本語</a></footer></div>
      
<style>
    
 .searchbar{float: right;}
    
 .image{text-align: center;}
    
 .setsumei{margin-left: 20px;
           margin-right: 20px;}
    
 .footer{width: 100%; 
           height: 40px; 
           text-align: center;
           border-top: 1px solid black; 
           position: absolute;
           bottom: 0;
           padding: 10px;}
    
 .page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -40px; 
}

 .page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block; 
  }

 .site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
  /* .push must be the same height as footer */
  height: 30px; 
}

 .site-footer {
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
    
    

 @media only screen and (max-width: 1130px) and (min-width: 480px) {
 .responsive-image-container{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        text-align: center;
      }
 img{width:85%;}
    }
        

 *, *:before, *:after {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
}    

 ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}

 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
    
 .cp_cont {
    height: auto;
}
    
/* menu */
 .cp_offcm03 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
            transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}
 .cp_offcm03 nav,
 .cp_offcm03 ul {
    height: 100%;
}

 .cp_offcm03 li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -6px;
}

 .cp_offcm03 a {
    display: block;    
    padding: 15px 45px;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .3s ease-in;
            transition: background-color .3s ease-in;
}
    
 .cp_offcm03 a:hover {
    background-color: lightgray;
}

/* menu toggle */
 #cp_toggle03 {
    display: none;
}

 #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_offcm03 {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
                    transform: translateX(0);
}

 #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_container {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
                    transform: translateX(0);
}

 .cp_mobilebar {
    display: none;
    
}

/* content */
 .cp_container {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    padding: 35px auto;
    -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease-in;
            transition: transform .3s ease-in;
}   

 .cp_content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 65vh;
    text-align: center;

}

@media (max-width: 1130px)and (min-width: 480px) {
/* menu */
 .cp_offcm03 {
        position: fixed;
        left: -250px;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        width: 250px;
        height: 100%;
        padding-top: 40px;
        color: black;
        background-color: white;
        z-index: 1000;
    }
    
    
 .cp_offcm03 nav {
        background: white;
        border-right: 0.5px solid lightgray;
        margin-left: -210px;
    }
    
    
    
 .cp_offcm03 li {
        display: block;
        margin-right: 0;}

        
        
 .cp_offcm03 a {
        padding: 20px;
        
    }
    
/* menu toggle */
 .cp_mobilebar {
        display: block;
        z-index: 2000;
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        padding: 0 25px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: white;
        border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;
        
        
    }
    
 .cp_menuicon {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        width: 25px;
        height: 100%;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease-in;
                transition: transform .3s ease-in;
    }
 .cp_menuicon > span {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 55%;
        margin-top: -0.3em;
        width: 100%;
        height: 0.2em;
        border-radius: 1px;
        background-color: black;
        -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease;
                transition: transform .3s ease;
    }
 .cp_menuicon > span:before,
 .cp_menuicon > span:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border-radius: 1px;
        background-color: black;
        -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease-in;
                transition: transform .3s ease-in;
    }
    
 .cp_menuicon > span:before {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-0.6em);
                transform: translateY(-0.6em);
    }
 
 .cp_menuicon > span:after {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0.6em);
                transform: translateY(0.6em);
    }

 #cp_toggle03:checked + .cp_mobilebar .cp_menuicon { 
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
                transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
    
 #cp_toggle03:checked + .cp_mobilebar span:before,
 #cp_toggle03:checked + .cp_mobilebar span:after {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
                transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
    
 #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_offcm03 {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
                transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    
 #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_container {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(250px);
                transform: translateX(250px);
    }
    
 input:checked ~ #h-menu_black {
    display: block;/*カバーを表示*/
    opacity: .6;
}
    
 #h-menu_black {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .7s ease-in-out;
}
    
/* content */
 .cp_container {
        top: 60px;
        height: 92vh;
        text-align: center; 
    } 
    
 .noscroll{
        overflow: hidden;
        position: fixed;
    }
    
</style> 
      
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML has lots of errors. Could you put it through a validator and correct them first and see if you still have the problem. If it’s still there then extract just enough code to demonstrate the problem see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The HTML and CSS I'm using are able to run everything that I'd like it to do without any problems. Unfortunately, I don't have enough knowledge of HTML, CSS, or JAVA to be able to fix any problems (if there are any). Do you see anything that might solve my back button problem?

Comment: it is Javascript - not Java... there is a big difference! But the above has loads of errors ~ the fact that modern browsers are more forgiving is in your favour.

Comment: So there is no coding that could help solve my issue?

Comment: We cannot see this effect with the code you have posted. I made all the necessary changes to the above and it passes the HTML validator now but there simply is not enough content for scrolling down  - due to the images being invalid references here probably.

Comment: Hi, I wasn’t saying that the invalid code is causing your problem, we just cannot tell that yet, but using an HTML validator is pretty easy, just search for one. A problem with invalid code is that it may seeem to work fine on a browser but either not work on another browser the same way or work differently in different circumstances.